# Android layout using Swipe View and Tile Strip

Tags: android, fragment

I'm making a new app, using the "Swipe View + Tile Strip" layout, but can't seem to figure out how to actually load different views into the fragments of the FragmentPagerAdapter?

Any help on this would be great (I'm still quite new to android development, so go easy ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Override `getItem()` and return a different fragment for each position.

Try something like this:

```
public class MyCustomFPAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyCustomFPAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return Fragment0.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return Fragment1.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return Fragment2.newInstance();
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return Fragment3.newInstance();
        } else {
            return DefaultFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but the code doesn't seem to be firing. Where should I put it?

Bit of code:

Comment: `code @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v = null;
         Bundle args = getArguments();
         if (args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
          v = getFirstView(inflater, container);
         }
         return v;
        }
        
        private View getFirstView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
         View v = null;
   TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
   tv.setText("FIRST");
         return v;
        }`

Comment: After quite a bit of playing around, I've got this to work. What i didn't fully understand was that I had to create a new class that extends Fragment for each layout. Thanks a lot! You get the tick!

Answer (score 1):

In a FragmentPagerAdapter you don't load Views, but Fragments.

Read the official documentation of FragmentPagerAdapter, which has a nice tutorial also. This is the first step to understand this Pager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This link has helped quite a bit, but I still don't understand how I can load in different things for different fragments, depending on the id.