# swipable dynamic fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to create a quiz programme where the users swipe between questions. The fragments need to be dynamic so i can load random questions and they need to be able to report back to the main activity so i can check whether they were right or wrong at the end.

My first problem im trying to attack are making the fragments dynamic. I have code below which creates static fragments. I send in a number (hard coded at the moment but it will be random) Each instance/fragment is saved in an array

My problem is when I try to create the fragments dynamically in the getItem method the programme falls over. Can anybody direct me... (Commented out static working example)

Also see: [Android layout using Swipe View and Tile Strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651939/android-layout-using-swipe-view-and-tile-strip)

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
{
    super(fm);
    /*
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(1));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(2));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(3));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(4));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(5));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(6));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(7));
    fragments.add(new QuestionScreen(8));
    fragments.add(new QuestionEnd());
    fragments.add(new QuestionStart());
    fragments.add(new QuestionEnd());
    */
    Log.w("he","hehehe");
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{

    if (position == 0) {        // change to switch statement
        return new QuestionScreen(1);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return new QuestionScreen(2);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return new QuestionScreen(3);
    } else if (position == 3) {
        return new QuestionScreen(4);
    } else {
        return new QuestionEnd();
    }
    //Log.w("se","sesese");
    //return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    Log.w("pe","pepepe");

    return fragments.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Why was my question voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was in getCount.

The method is trying to return fragments.size when no fragments were actually added.

removing it fixes the problem